# Ativando modulo cgi bin web c++

Tags: c++, aplicação-web, cgi

Pessoal eu instalei o cgicc com a finalidade de entender como funciona o cgi
porem ativei o include mod_cgi do meu apache2 no slackware mas ao criar um cgi e colocar em /var/www/cgi-bin o mesmo só faz o download do arquivo de cgi que esta dentro da pasta:

qtest é o binario cgi que o proprio criou em /srv/www/cgi-bin

http://localhost/cgi-bin/qtest

as configuraçoes estao identicas a esta abaixo:

AllowOverride None
   Options ExecCGI
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all

Options All

fiz com base neste site:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_web_programming.htm

peguei até mesmo um exemplo deste site compilei e coloqueo em /var/www/cgi-bin mas ele faz o download do mesmo ao invés de executar qual é o problema?